# can add 1 to a char array, cant add k to same array of k=1.. WHY?

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

edit: How do i get this while function to work. I want k to be added to whatevers inside the vektor[x] slot.

```
char vektor[]=str.toCharArray();
int k =0, x=4;
    while(x>0){
        vektor[x]=(char)vektor[x]+k;
        System.out.println(vektor[x]);
        x--;
        k++;

    }
```

Comment: If it's not working, then chances are there is an error message. Just a hunch, but you may need to cast the result of `k1+'A'` which would be an `int` to a `char`.

Comment: Where is k defined for `vektor[k]`? As was mentioned, you might be adding an Int to a Char and the operator may not like that.

Comment: Use `vektor[x] += k` it has implicit casting in it, so you shall not cast anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the k variable? 
vektor[k] doesn't exists

```
vektor[kl] = kl + 'A';
```

However this will expression yields an integer. You have to use a cast

```
vektor[k] = (char) (kl + 'A');
```

Comment: the assumption is that `k` is defined earlier

Comment: Okej but how do I use this in a while function which is the whole point. Like the following, I want to add k to the variable thats inside vektor[x]. I tried the following which is wrong  'vektor[x]=(char)vektor[x]+kl;'

Comment: put in around curly braces. vektor[x]=(char)(vektor[x]+kl)

Answer (score 0):

int and char are 2 different simple types. Nevertheless an int can be cast to an char. This is what happens when you do `char c = 'a' + 1;` the compiles sees, that the evaluation of 'a' + 1 needs to be a char and adds casts to this.

But when you try to add a declared int to an char the compiler assumes that this declared int is an int and no char and an error occurs. The way to say the compiler that you are know what you are doing is to add an explicit cast: `charArray[i] = (char) (kl + 'a');`. Now first the 'a' is converted to a int the addition is done and the returning int gets cast to an char.

Answer (score -1):

you have to chast to char, try this:

```
vektor[k]=(char)(kl+'A');
```

I forgot to add parenthesis to the last part. This should function.